# Image upload working in web but not for react native app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

```
createFormData = (photo) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", {
        name: photo.fileName,
        type: photo.type,
        uri: Platform.OS === "android" ? photo.uri : photo.uri.replace("file://", "")
    });
    return data;
};
uploadImage() {[enter image description here][1]
    let formdata = this.createFormData(this.state.selectedImage)
    return postFile(EndPoints.ADVISOR_PROFILE_IMAGE_UPLOAD, formdata)
}
```

Post Request method

```
export function postFile(url, body) { 
return axios({
     method: 'post', url: SERVICE_URL + url, headers: headersForFile, data: body 
    });
}
```

#

Request Payload is showing [Object, Object]

#

From server getting error as file location not found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcIEZ.png)

Comment: show the post method code

Comment: export function postFile(url, body) {
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: SERVICE_URL + url,
    headers: headersForFile,
    data: body
  });
}

Comment: try this axios post format and let me know if this works *axios(
        {
            method: 'post',
            url: URL,
            data: userData,
            config: {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }
        }
    );*

Comment: Hey Abhinav !!
R you sure you have used Permissions perfectly. How you are accessing/reading storage of user?

Comment: import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
Using local storage

Comment: Actually from backend I'm getting error like "File location not found"

Comment: have you tested the api from postman....is it working??

Comment: Yes , It's working, But from mobile I'm getting status 400 error

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when using FormData with React Native, enabling Debug Js Remotely tends to show weird issues. This is happening because of the issue of Chrome debugger or React Native debugger dealing with FormData.